# SQL INNER JOIN or BEST OPTION?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to request help from someone who is having good experience with `INNER JOIN`..Here i have two tables

```
Table 1
===========
id | name 
===========
1  | john
2  | mark

Table 2
======================================
id | customer_id | like_to_eat
======================================
1  | 1           | cake
2  | 2           | cake
3  | 1           | pudding
4  | 1           | chocolate
```

I wanted query to find out which customers would like to eat "cake"

I have done this

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 
ON table1.id = table2.customer_id 
WHERE table2.like_to_eat ='cake'
```

but then again i am not getting the correct `$row['id']`

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What are you getting?  You have two columns named `id`.

Comment: i am getting the table2.id currently but i needs table1.id

Comment: Then add `table1.id AS table1Id` or similar

Comment: You should always explicitly list the columns you want. Especially when using joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments

```
SELECT table1.id as TheIDIReallyNeed
, table1.name
, table2.id
, table2.customer_id
, table2.like_to_eat
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 
ON table1.id = table2.customer_id 
WHERE table2.like_to_eat ='cake'
```

Comment: Thank you...it's fixed with using SELECT table1.* FROM etc...

Comment: I was illustrating that the * is equivalent to specifying all columns and I aliased of the one that was being asked for in the question/comments.